# Expectation of minimum of uniformly random subset of $\{2^1,2^2,⋯,2^{10}\}$?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, expected-value

Choose a random subset of  $\{2^1,2^2,⋯,2^{10}\}$  by selecting each of the 10 elements independently with probability  $\frac{1}{2}$. Find the expected value of the smallest element in the subset (e.g. the subset can be  $\{2^1,2^3,2^4,2^7\}$. The smallest element is $2^1$).

- I am not sure how to approach this question.  I did however try to do $\{(2^1*1)+(2^2*2)+\cdots+(2^{10}*10)\}$ and did not get the right answer.

Any assistance would help.

Comment: What happens if no element is chosen? How is the smallest element defined then?

Comment: i.e. empty set $\{\}$?  Then the smallest value would be $0$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value is $\sum_{2^k\in \{2^1,2^2,....,2^{10}\}} P(2^k$ is the smallest item in the set$)\times 2^k$.

The way I see it, the way that the least element is $2^k$ is if all the $2^{j_{j< k}}$ are not chosen and $2^k$ is.  The probability of that is $\frac 1{2^{k-1}}\times \frac 12 = \frac 1{2^k}$. So $P(2^k$ is the smallest item in the set$)= \frac 1{2^k}$.  So the expected value is $\sum_{k=1}^{10} \frac 1{2^k}\times 2^k = 10$.

This assumes if the set has no elements we consider the least of zero elements as $0$.  If we simple exclude this for the sample space, then our probabilities are all bumped up by a facto for $\frac {2^{10}}{2^{10} - 1}$ and our expected value is $10 \frac {2^{10}}{2^{10} - 1} = 10.0097...$

Answer (score 2):

The probability that $2$ is chosen is $\frac12$.

The probability that $2^2$ is the smallest element chosen is $\left(\frac12\right)^2$. We do not pick $2$ and then pick $2^2$.

In general, the probability of $2^k$ is the smallest element  is $\left( \frac12 \right)^k$.

Hence it should be evaluated to be $$\sum_{k=1}^{10}2^k\cdot  \left( \frac12\right)^k=10$$

Comment: Can you share how you break down the equation above and show how you get to $10$.  I'm still trying to understand this type of equation.

Comment: We have $2^k \cdot \left( \frac12 \right)^k=1$, hence I am just summing $1$ ten times.